# How can I change the language of libreoffice calc's formulas?

Tags: formula, libreoffice, calc

In excel all formulas are translated, e.g. I can write SUMME instead of SUM, or HEUTE instead of TODAY.
I can't find an option to change the language, except for the UI. Is it possible to change the language of the formulas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Formula -> Use English function names (under "Formula Options", just after "Formula syntax"; default: yes).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't see that option.